# How to use a literal type value as the discriminant of a discriminated union?

Tags: typescript, discriminated-union

I'd like to use [rex-tils](https://github.com/Hotell/rex-tils) `Enum` (somewhat similar to a [String literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#string-literal-types)), as the discrimant of a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#discriminated-unions).

In other words, considering the following (simplified) example, I'd like to let the `Animal` type know that `name` should be of `AnimalType` (as opposed to `string`):

```js
type AnimalName = "cat" | "dog"

type Cat = {
    name: "cat"
    meows: true
}

type Dog = {
    name: "dog"
    barks: true
}

type Animal = Cat | Dog

const scream = (animal: Animal) => {
    if (animal.name === "cat") {
        return animal.meows;
    } else {
        return animal.barks;
    }
}
```

I was expecting that I could do:

```
type Cat = {
    name: AnimalName['cat']
}
```

But I get the following error:

```
Property 'cat' does not exist on type '"cat" | "dog"'.
```

Is there any way I can achieve this?

Cf. TypeScript playground [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20AnimalName%20%3D%20%22cat%22%20%7C%20%22dog%22%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20Cat%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20%22cat%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20meows%3A%20true%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20Dog%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20%22dog%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20barks%3A%20true%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20Animal%20%3D%20Cat%20%7C%20Dog%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20scream%20%3D%20(animal%3A%20Animal)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(animal.name%20%3D%3D%3D%20%22cat%22)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20animal.meows%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20animal.barks%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A)

Comment: Could you include some examples of uses of your proposed types, including code where you'd like to see errors?  Without such code I can only guess about this... guesses: change `AnimalName` to `enum AnimalName {cat, dog}` as in [this](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/KYOwrgtgBAgiCWECGAbAckiwoG8oGMkAXAGigBMB7AcygF8BuAKCaIE8AHbAYWKgF5cTKCKghMwAFywEydBIB0hIsNFZKAdwDO0ogCcwwJnRbsuUACI0BQ0WInS4iVBiwKq1VSIBGSPQGsdKH1DY1NObCc5G14iKAAfSxoWfEoQLTitfD1gTBsACiRZVEdilABKAQA+W1F4ADMoQrKFcSwBfkEol0VlSpwvOygcojA9ECgi5xQFdW1mOzooYBQtbAGh0RGxiam5BV8ArQXREzogA)?  ‍♂️

Comment: You can use `Extract<AnimalName, 'cat' >`. But this seems a bit wierd.. How about defining AnimalName in relation to the union :`type AnimalName =Animal['name'] `

Comment: Thanks @jcalz & @Titian Cernicova-Dragomir, these are 3 great solutions to my problem. Kudos for understanding my need even though I wasn't sure I had made it clear. :) — In my context, I can't use `enum` so I'll go with one of Titian's suggestions.